# cordova bluetooth plugin to enable ,scan and connect bluetooth

Tags: android, ios, cordova, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have adding bluetooth plugin
https://github.com/tanelih/phonegap-bluetooth-plugin
afterwards how allow to enable bluetooth in my application and scanning nearby device and connecting to scanned anyone of device.what are the steps add to my coding  my index.html ,index.js .Anyone known please help me .i am beginner. i want to know that one.

Answer (score 1):

Be carefull it s an old plugin.

Please take a look at this plugin with more documentation and up to date :
https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial

Comment: i need to know how to enable the bluetooth ,scan and connect  the other device when i open my application

Comment: look the documentation, there is lots of method, bluetoothSerial.list to scan and bluetoothSerial.connect to connect.